# python - find matching sentences in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a text file which contains 35k words in paragraphs. Sample below

```
This sentence does repeat? This sentence does not repeat! This sentence does not repeat. This sentence does repeat.
This sentence does repeat. This sentence does not repeat! This sentence does not repeat. This sentence does repeat!
```

I wanted to identify matching sentences. One way I managed to find is to split the paragraphs into separate lines using `.`, `!`, `?` etc. as the delimiter's and look for matching lines.

Code

```
import collections as col

with open('txt.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = f.read().replace('. ','.\n').replace('? ','?\n').replace('! ','!\n').splitlines()
print([i for i, n in col.Counter(l).items() if n > 1])
```

Please suggest some better approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
import re
...
l = re.split(r'[?!.]*',f.read())
```

Comment: got this error `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0`

Comment: @VanPeer my apologies, I made a regex mistake. I since updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: thanks, seems to be working! Got this warning message 
`re.py:212: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match. return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)`

Comment: @VanPeer you’re welcome. This is due to the fact that Python will throw an exception if it turns out there aren’t any actual sentences. So for this case, it’s fine, but in general, you’d want to do some specific error handling or look into more about Regular Expressions in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarentee it would be the fastest, but I would try to exploit the speed of `sort`. First I would split the text by punctuation to give a list of sentances, then run sort on the list to order all the sentances, then finally loop through the list and count the number of consecutive sentances that are the same and store the sentance and count in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a different. The regex module is very powerful:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

pat = r'(\?)|(\.)|(!)'
c = Counter()
with open('filename') as f:
       for line in f:
              c[re.sub(pat, '\n', line)] += 1
```

This creates a regex pattern matching `?, . or !` and replaces it with a `\n`.
Using the for loop, this happens on a line basis.